# POST to Google Apps Script web app does use latest version

Tags: post, google-apps-script

I have built a web app using Google Apps Script, and a lot of information from here, that writes data to a spreadsheet for me. All of the functionality is in the doPost() function and works fine in testing within the GAS environment.

I built a straight HTML, CSS, and Javascript web application to act as the UI front-end and it POSTs fine to the GAS web app ... until I add code to the latter, that is. Once I do that, I keep getting the old version of the GAS app.

I have updated the version, checked to ensure the key has not changed on me, waited 24 hours ... I am missing something fundamental. The only thing that works is opening a new script project, copying the updated code into it, publishing it, and changing the URL reference in my other code. Then I will see the changes.

Needless to say, this is getting tedious. Any pointers to where the problem lies?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you created a new version after the changes and published the Web App with the new version? [Versions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_versions)

Comment: I think I am. I go to Publish > Deploy as Web App and click the Update button, then click OK in the next dialog. They URL does not change. One note: I cannot change the version number. It only allows me to select the current version number.

Comment: Ah! There is the Manage Versions menu to add new versions. Thanks for getting me to look around on how to change versions.

Comment: This question is a dup. User not saving new version

Comment: What is the difference between clicking update with the same version and setting version to new and clicking. Isn't new code being run either way. My version number is now huge!?!?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is that I needed to choose File > Manage Version and save a new version. That allowed me to re-publish using the new version number, which contains the updates. Simply re-publishing under the old version number does not do what you might expect.

That now explains the problem I had with another script...

Answer (score 1):

There are two versions of the web app, practically speaking.  There is the published version as it existed when you published it and the development version, which reflects your code as it currently exists in the editor.  You can access your updated code in its current state without re-publishing by clicking on the "*Test web app for your latest code*" link in **Publish >  Deploy as web app**.  This will provide you a link with /dev in it instead of /exec.

```
Published:  https://script.google.com/macros/s/ABCD1234ABCD1234/exec
Development:  https://script.google.com/a/macros/<domain>/s/ABCD1234ABCD1234/dev
```

Comment: You should also mention that the .dev link is only working for the script owner and editors who have write access to the script (this feature was added on March 2013) this is an important information.

Comment: I don't believe the dev version currently works. I've been trying it and the only way to make a POST request to the updated script is to publish it as a new version.